# I am using select tag in bootstrap and I am using css for changing the background of select box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `select` tag in bootstrap and I am using CSS for changing the background of select box. Is this a good practice? or any built-in classes are there in bootstrap to change `background-color`?

**HTML**

```
<select class="select">
    <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>30</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.select{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can use classes to apply background for the selectbox. This is not considered as bad practice as long as your code is W3 Standard.

Also here is a slectbox for bootstrap with many features 
[Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Comment: You can mark if this has answered your question. This would be grateful from you.